# Multiple queries dependent on each other

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have two queries both dependent on each other, i.e. if first query is not executed the second shouldn't be executed, and the other way around if second can't be executed the first shouldn't be executed.

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,2,3)
UPDATE `otherTable` SET `val1`=1 WHERE `id`=$idOfInsert
```

`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is not the answer.

I tried using `mysqli::multi_query` but as it turned out it executes the first even though the second can't be executed (it stops on error).

How can I achieve this in PHP?

Comment: "if second can't be executed the first shouldn't be executed" This requirement is a direct challenge to logic. Impossible

Comment: @HankyPanky Database transactions were specifically made to handle these cases, in order to guarantee consistancy.

Comment: What it the finishing state you want based on the starting state? You don't clearly say. PS An update command/statement is not a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for are transactions. @tmuguet's answer has really helped me back then, but now looking at it from the perspective of time I would like to provide a more up to date answer.

Each query needs to be executed separately and using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

```
try {
    // Start transaction
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $mysqli->query('INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,2,3)');

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE otherTable SET val1=1 WHERE id=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $idOfInsert);
    $stmt->execute();

    // Commit changes
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // Something went wrong. Rollback
    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Of course for this to work properly you need to have mysqli error reporting enabled. Just add this line before `new mysqli()` in your code.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use transactions, if the engine you use support it (InnoDB, BDB).

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html for examples.

Edit: quick example using *mysqli*:

```
$connection->autocommit(FALSE); // disable auto-commit and start a new transaction
$result  = $connection->query("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,2,3)");
$result &= $connection->query("UPDATE `otherTable` SET `val1`=1 WHERE `id`=$idOfInsert");
if (!$result) {
  // One of the queries has failed: cancel the transaction
  $connection->rollback();
} else {
  // Both queries worked:commit the current transaction
  $connection->commit();
}
$connection->autocommit(TRUE); // enable auto-commit
```

You may want to optimize the queries (i.e. not execute the second one if the first has failed, use prepared statements, ...)

Comment: Added upvote since transaction are not only a great option to make queries depended, but they are also able to prevent dataloss on disconnect during transactions etc. (thats why its called transactions haha)

Comment: Does [THIS](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.quickstart.transactions.php) concern me?

Comment: If your are not using *mysqlnd_ ms*, no. As it seems you use *mysqli*, definitely no.

Comment: One more thing: why not `&=` instead of `|=` ?

Comment: Because you want the transaction to stop if one of the query fails (OR). But clearly, this is not a good way to manage transactions if you have more queries.

Comment: If $connection->query fails it returns false. False | False = False; False | True = true; true | true = true;
False & true = false; true & true = true

Answer (score -1):

Use [INSERT IGNORE] to make the SQL server ignore the errors.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `table` VALUES (1,2,3);
```

Then use LAST_INSERT_ID() to get the inserted ID or 0 if nothing was inserted. This will make UPDATE fail if since there is no record with an ID = 0.

```
UPDATE `otherTable` SET `val1`=1 WHERE `id`=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score -3):

Break it into multiple query calls:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT ...");
if ($result) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE ...");
}
```

But the "don't do first if second can't" is impossible. PHP cannot reach back in time and warn the first query that the second one has failed.

Comment: mysql_query() is deprecated as of 5.5, you want mysqli_query().

Comment: "PHP cannot reach back in time".. actually the mysqli / mysql functions of PHP support transactions. Transactions check if all querys ran properly. If one of them failed, it will 'undo' (rollback) the queries