# "Lock wait timeout exceeded" for failed transaction with "SET autocommit=0"

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm not sure if I understand it. I have tables defined as such:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blgBs` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `fid` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `dtm` INT UNSIGNED
) ENGINE='InnoDB', COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B_Ts` (`
    `id` INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `bid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `tid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    "FOREIGN KEY fk_cbt_bid (`bid`) REFERENCES `blgBs`(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
") ENGINE='InnoDB', COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci');
```

I'm running the following multi-query through a PHP engine [`mysqli_multi_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) on a shared web hosting platform:
(I understand that there's no need to use transaction for just one `INSERT`. It's just for this example. In my future code, I will have multiple delete & inserts in that statement.)

```
SET autocommit=0;
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `blgBs` (`fid`, `dtm`) VALUES ('ZLUDMHS8', '1589094000');
COMMIT;
SET autocommit=1;
```

If there's already a row, say:

```
fid = ZLUDMHS8
dtm = 1
```

That multi-part query fails:

> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry 'ZLUDMHS8' for key 'fid'

But if I run it again, I get a long pause and then:

> ## 1205 - Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

What am I doing wrong?

PS. I'm running it on MySQL v.`5.7.28`

Comment: Why `multi_query`? Why not just use the [`begin_transaction`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) function plus `commit()` and do it normally? `multi_query` is super dangerous to use since it doesn't support placeholder values.

Comment: @tadman hmm. Thanks for suggestion. I've never used `mysqli_begin_transaction`. Does it replace `SET autocommit=0` and `BEGIN` in my example?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61123168/1839439 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60476517/1839439

Comment: @Dharman thanks. I'm assuming `mysqli_report` is needed so that `mysql_*` functions throw exceptions, right? I'm curious, do I need to revert error reporting back after I'm done with that transaction? And if so then how?

Comment: @Dharman also what is that slash for in `catch (\Throwable $e)`?

Comment: Error reporting should be switched on always. No matter if you use transactions or not. You must have mysqli error reporting switched on. The `\Throwable` is just a global namespace. Once you learn about namespaces you will understand what it is.

Comment: Also, I recommend learning PDO instead of mysqli. It is much easier to use.

Comment: @Dharman how do i get previous value that `mysqli_report()` changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214489/discussion-between-dharman-and-c00000fd).